# javascript - "this" is undefined when method is bound to event listener

Tags: javascript, this, addeventlistener, event-listener

I already tried to understand what the this keyword refers to by reading about it. well, that didn't help. so please help me on this one!
where is the difference between the manual function call and the binding to the event listener?

```
var app = {
    foo: true,
    bar: function() {
        console.log("this",this.foo);
        console.log("app",app.foo);
    }
}

app.bar();
/*  this true
    app true    */

document.addEventListener("click", app.bar);
/*  this undefined
    app true    */
```

thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not `this`, but `foo` that is undefined because `this` is `document` when `app.bar` is bound as event listener to `document`. So `this.foo` becomes `document.foo` which is undefined.

```
document.foo = "document.foo";

var app = {
    foo: true,
    bar: function() {
        console.log("this",this.foo);
        console.log("app",app.foo);
    }
};

app.bar();
/*  this true
    app true    */

document.addEventListener("click", app.bar);
/*  this document.foo
    app true    */
```

you can bind the context

```
document.addEventListener("click", app.bar.bind(app));
```

or use a function to call `app.bar`

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    app.bar();
});
```

Comment: that anonymous function did the trick. thanks, that was quick!

Answer (score 6):

Inside your `document.addEventListener` `this` will refer to `document`, since you are calling a function of `document` object. When you are calling `app.bar()` directly, `this` refers to `app` object for the same reason.
If you want to refer to `app` you have to manually redefine function's context, using `bind()`:

```
document.addEventListener("click", app.bar.bind(app));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a lucky hit here... tried it with the [module pattern](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript)
I never got closures but they seem to work for me here. If anybody's got a good read about closures, please comment!

```
var app = (function() {
    var foo = true;

    return {
        bar: function() {
            console.log(foo);
        }
    };

})();

app.bar(); //true
document.addEventListener("click", app.bar); //true
```

EDIT: Sorry, I just figured that this has nothing to do with the this keyword anymore.

Answer (score 0):

document.addEventListener("click", app.bar.bind(app);